How to find and replace superscripted Numbers wrapped in square brackets in Microsoft word
I need to find all superscripted numbers wrapped in the square brackets like this [23] for example but for any number up to 90. Because I cited some references like [1] down to [90]
but now I need to replace all instances of these superscripts to occur without the brackets and just the number alone. So it looks like 23 24 25 26...

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please post online an example document (OneDrive, Dropbox etc) and let's have its link.

You can find superscripted text by applying a format in the Search/Replace dialogue, and you can use a wildcard to match numbers. You'll have to escape the brackets with \ since they have a meaning when using wildcards.
In your case:

Go to Search/Replace (control-H),
With the cursor on the Find What area, select Format / Font / Superscript,
Select Use Wildcards,
Put \[([0-9]@)\]in the Find What area and \1in the Replace With area,
Hit Replace All.

